# Apache Derby extracting the maximum value from a table

Tags: sql, derby

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
  hora,
  SUM(cada_hora) AS suma_hora
FROM
  info
GROUP BY
  hora;
```

Which outputs a table with all the hours (from 0 to 23) along with their respective sums, like this;

```
Hora | Suma_hora
-----------------
0    | 100000
1    | 200000
2    | 150000
3    | 450000
4    | 120000
...  | ...
```

Now what I'd like to do is to extract from that table the one row with the maximum value for `Suma_hora` and show the hour and the respective max value. So it would look like this:

```
Hora | Max_hora
-----------------
3    | 450000
```

The closest I can get to my desired answer is this, but unfortunately I don't know how to get it to display the respective hour as well (it only shows the max value, i.e., `Max_hora`):

```
SELECT
  MAX(suma_hora) AS Max_hora
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      hora,
      SUM(cada_hora) AS suma_hora
    FROM
      info
    GROUP BY
      hora
  ) AS resultado;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

NB: Adding the following bit gives an error, so it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  hora, MAX(suma_hora) AS Max_hora
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as pie amigo mío :) just order by hora, and take the first, like this:

```
SELECT
  hora,
  SUM(cada_hora) AS suma_hora
FROM
  info
GROUP BY
  hora
Order by suma_hora DESC Limit 1;
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! I will accept your answer shortly :D gracias

Comment: I've always loved to Help! :)